# Googlebot and AmazonBot trying to access every Drupal page I edit

Tags: log-messages

Ok, this is extremely weird.

The point is, everytime I edit a node on my website, and then go to the "recent logs" page, I **always** see a request (with "access denied") from an IP owned by Google or Amazon for the same node/edit page I had just visited, right before (or after) the line saying that i had modified that node.

I've tried from 2 different PCs, using different browsers... same behaviour. 
Another drupal site on the same server doesn't have this "issue".

What is happening? Why is GoogleBot stalking me?

I've tried copying the entire site to another domain and the result is absolutely the same.

@beebee: they are completely different sites... it would be like looking for a needle in a haystack and I have no idea of where to start from.

@Alfred Armstrong: no google toolbars or other weird extensions... plus, I was wondering: how can they be so fast? I mean, I see the request **immediately**... I'm thinking more of a logging error from Drupal for obscure reasons.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the differences between the 2 sites?

Comment: Have you got toolbars installed on your browser? The Google toolbar for one will try to index every page you visit.

Comment: My experience has been that this is caused by browsers. One difference between the sites may be in the robots.txt file, as Google will generally respect this.

Comment: i've tried with chrome, firefox and ie.... always the same. Plus, the crawler request is so immediate that I don't think it's possible it's a real request. I mean, shouldn't it take at least a few minutes before the crawler comes?

Comment: I have the exact weird issue but in addtition to googlebots it is also happening by ip addresses which are owned by reputed vps digitalocean. Searching that ip gives results in abuse ip and most of them are recently added into abuseipdb. 
The point here is how come remote host mimicking the activity (refhttps://www.drupal.org/node/554982#comment-4636500)? Nearest issue I fount in DO is very old https://www.drupal.org/forum/general/general-discussion/2005-08-23/access-denied-in-admin#comment-59264